# How do I check cells neighbour in Canvas.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have made a grid and need to check whether a cell has a or several bombs around it, but I'm a bit confused on how to do it now. I have tried this code;

```
function placeNumbers() {
        for (let x = -ColumnRow; x < ColumnRow * 3; x += ColumnRow) {
            for (let y = -ColumnRow; y < ColumnRow * 3; y += ColumnRow) {
                if (cells[x].bomb == false) {
                   //do something 
                }
        }
    }
}
```

but then it says that I can't use .bomb. What can I do? I have made a class Cell which has a bomb feature and if a bomb is on the cell then the cell should have bomb = true. So then i have to check wether the neighbour of a cell does has the bomb true or false?
Does anyone have any tips or know what to do here?

Here's a sample of the code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")


class Cell {
    constructor(x, y, w) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.w = w
        this.bomb = false
        this.revealed = false
    }
    show() {
        const cell = new Path2D();
        cell.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.w);
        ctx.stroke(cell);
        this.cell = cell;
    }
}


const w = canvas.width
const h = canvas.height
const ColumnRow = w / 15
const cells = []
const bombs = 10
let checked = true
let bombPosition = []

function setup() {
    for (let x = 0; x < w - 1; x += ColumnRow) {
        for (let y = 0; y < h - 1; y += ColumnRow) {
            cells.push(new Cell(x, y, ColumnRow))
        }
    }
}

function drawCells() {
    for (let c of cells) {
        c.show()
    }
}

function numOfBombs() {
    for (let i = 0; i < bombs; i++) {
        randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * w / ColumnRow) * ColumnRow
        randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * h / ColumnRow) * ColumnRow

        bombPosition.push({ x: randomX, y: randomY });
    }
}

function drawBomb() {
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < bombPosition.length; i++) {
            ctx.drawImage(img, bombPosition[i].x, bombPosition[i].y, ColumnRow, ColumnRow)
        }
    };
    img.src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/americosp/Minesweeper/master/Minesweeper/images/mine.png";
}

function bombCollision(cell) {
    for (let i = 0; i < bombPosition.length; i++) {
        if (cell.x == bombPosition[i].x && cell.y == bombPosition[i].y) {
            console.log("same position");
        }
    }
}

canvas.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    for (const cell of cells) {
        if (ctx.isPointInPath(cell.cell, e.offsetX, e.offsetY)) {
            ctx.clearRect(cell.x, cell.y, cell.w, cell.w);
            checked = true
            cell.revealed = true
            bombCollision(cell)
        } else {
            /* ctx.clearRect(cell.x, cell.y, cell.w, cell.w); */
        }
    }
});


function update() {
    drawCells()
    if (checked) {
        drawBomb()
        // coverCell()
        checked = false
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

function update2() {
    numOfBombs()
    setup()
}
update2()
update()
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: `i` is undefined in  `if (cells[i].bomb == false) {` thus `cells[undefined] === undefined` and `undefined` does not have any properties Eg `bomb` You need to calculate the cell index from the x, y coordinates you are iterating

Comment: @Blindman67 My bad is was supposed to say x and not i, but i still get the error that i cant use .bomb. do you have any examples on how i should do it?